# Center value in statistical table

Tags: floats

how to center value for a better-looking table, Here is my suggestion and the output.

```
 \documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
 \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{booktabs} % For better looking tables
 \usepackage{natbib}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[figurename=Fig.,skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

 \usepackage{siunitx}
  \newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1,group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=3]}
  \newcolumntype{U}[1]{S[table-format=#1,round-precision=2,round-mode=places]}


  \begin{document}
  \begin{table}[ht]
 \caption{Descriptive statistics}
 \label{tab:tab_Descriptive statistics}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{@{} l U{3.0} U{4.2}U{4.2} U{4.2} U{4.2}  @{}}
 \toprule 
 Variables & {Price} & {Open} & {High} & {Low} & {Vol}&  \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(l){6-6}  

No of obs.              & 3643     &    3643     & 3643      & 3643      &   3643\\  
Mean                    & 70.814   &   70.83     & 71.885    & 69.687    &  \\ 
St.\ Dev.               & 23.701979&    23.65      &    23.768370&  23.543701&   100\\
    Miximum                 &-37.63    &    -14.0      &    13.69    &  -40.32   &   100\\
Manimum                 & 145.29   &    145.19     &    147.27   &  143.22   &  100\\
    25\%                    & 50.99    &    51.0       &51.98      &    50.13    &  10\\
50\%                    & 68.10    &    68.15      &    69.31    &  67.0     &     100\\
75\%                    & 91.86   & 91.77        &  92.92    &  90.70    &     100\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

output :

[image]

Comment: Which values do you want to centre?

Comment: @Bernard value of the Number of observations is not aligned with others' values!

Comment: That's a classic problem with column headers in S column type. Adding  a pair of braces around each header should solve the problem. It is also possible you should add as an option for the S column formatting `table-number-alignment=center` (by default, it is the decimal dot that is centred).

Comment: If I compile the code you posted, I end up with a result significantly different than the image in your question which you labelled "output". I also noticed, that the values you used as arguments for your `U` column type don't necessarily match the contents of the particular column. You may want to fix them.

Comment: I think you should also change `U{3.0} U{4.2}U{4.2} U{4.2} U{4.2}` to `*{4}{U{-2.2}} S[table-format=3.0]`.

Comment: @leandriis Hi my friend, the table belongs to a research paper that I'm writing, I just copied  the code from From my texniccenter editor then have done a screenshot from the compiled  PDF

Comment: @Haithem: You may want to start by making the code compilable. Currently it results in an error message due to teh extra `&` right after `{Vol}`. Do not look at a pdf that you get after an error message but fix the error message(s) first. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: @leandriis you are right, I'm always getting this advice from you . it is just sometimes i cannot fix error messages. i'm trying to do my best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose numbers of `No of obs.` in curly braces:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For better looking tables
\usepackage[figurename=Fig.,skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Descriptive statistics}
    \label{tab:tab_Descriptive statistics}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{S[table-format=3.2,
                             round-mode=places,
                             round-precision=2]}
                           S[table-format=2]  
                @{}}
    \toprule
 Variables      & {Price}   & {Open}    & {High}        & {Low}         & {Vol}  \\ % <---
    \midrule
No of obs.      & {3643}    & {3643}    & {3643}        & {3643}        & {3643}\\
Mean            & 70.814    &  70.83    &  71.885       &   69.687      &       \\
St. Dev.        & 23.701979 &  23.65    &  23.768370    &   23.543701   & 100   \\
    Miximum     &-37.63     & -14.0     &  13.69        &  -40.32       & 100   \\
    Manimum     & 145.29    & 145.19    & 147.27        &  143.22       & 100   \\
\qty{25}{\%}    & 50.99     &  51.0     &  51.98        &   50.13       &  10   \\
\qty{55}{\%}    & 68.10     &  68.15    &  69.31        &   67.0        & 100   \\
\qty{75}{\%}    & 91.86     &  91.77    &  92.92        &   90.70       & 100   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]